# CSS not applying to Enterprise Wiki custom page layout

Tags: css, page-layout, enterprise-wiki, design-manager

I've created a new master page and page layout in Design Manager. When I preview the page layout in Design Manager, the layout appears correctly with no errors (see below).

[image]

The new layout also appears in the Page Layout options

[image]

However, when I apply the new page layout to a page, it seems that the stylesheet is not linked as it kicks out the text without the hero unit, text styles, columns, etc.

[image]

I've checked in SP designer that the CSS file is checked in and published and the .css link shows up in the HTML page layout file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check if browser is loading the same CSS file in View Source of it? If not you would need to check if the page layout and CSS files are published.